# AlertDialog background activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog that displays correctly as I intend it to. The problem is that when I trigger the alert from any activity, it opens what appears to be a blank layout then opens the alert dialog box inside the blank layout. I want my alert dialog box to open in the activity that the user is in when they trigger it. This is my code:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_about_t2m, null))
    .create();  
    dialog.setTitle("About T2M");
    dialog.show();
```

I thought that the problem may be the second argument but how do I even detect the current activity?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

To build an AlertDialog:

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
 builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

You can also refer the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DialogFragment  for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Activity with a transparent background that has the Alert Dialog. Just launch this activity from anywhere in Application and you will get an Alert Dialog with your current Activity in Background:

To make the Activity transparent use below code:

```
<activity
            android:name="name of your Activity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this-

```
 View v =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_about_t2m, null);
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setView(v)
    .create();  
    dialog.setTitle("About T2M");
    dialog.show();
```