# Screen blinks if there are multiple activities

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

Can anyone pls help me with this:

I have an activity where I am pressing on a menu item on click of which am starting a new Activity which does nothing i.e. its a blank screen which in turns calls other Activity which is responsible for the UI dialog which is expected at the final stage.

When i click on that menu item, screen blinks and then that dialog is shown. As there are two activities getting started back to back on click of menu item. I don't want that screen blink to happen.

Pls help as I am new to android

Answer (score 0):

yes, you figured it out right.
Calling two activities back to back leads screen to blink.
Why don't you directly call the UI activity from your current activity.
I mean, is it very important for you to use the intermmediate activity?
if not, remove it.

and if you only want to display a dialog box, use `dialogFragment` instead.

see this link for more details:-
[AlertDialog background activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938795/alertdialog-background-activity/17938936#17938936)

Comment: yes it is important for me to call mid activity as it checks some cases if we really need to call the third activity. Depends on some mechanism.

Comment: I have an activity A which has a menu "send sms" on click of which it starts an activity "MessageSendingCon". In this activity, it checks some conditions and start an Activity "SendSmsActivity" which shows a dialog to the user .  

I want the Second activity to run in background as its responsible for the screen to blink/.... or any way out to avoid the screen blink

Anyone any idea

Comment: as far as i can imagine, is that in your second activity, you are performing some condition checks.
if you are doing so, you can use those condition checking in a simple java class file also, that can extend the `mainactivity`.
and then you can invoke the `SendSMSActivity` from there as required.

You can also try removing the `setContentView` from the second activity and see, whether it removes blinking or not

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, removing the call to the method 
`setContentView()`
should solve the problem.

But the best practice is not to call an ACTIVITY class if you don't actually want something to be displayed in the screen. There are plenty of other options to check the condition, I by myself like to encapsulate checking conditions into one boolean checkCondition() method in the first activity.